# Powershell can't fill HTML form

Tags: html, powershell

I'm trying to fill `username/password` info form, but I can't find a property called `value` if I inspect the `username` field, what can I do?

Inspect of the field gives this element:

```
input _ngcontent-xft-c3="" aria-label="Username" autocomplete="off" class="login_form_input--colors login_form_input--typography ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-touched" formcontrolname="username" id="username" type="text"
```

Comment: this is probably an `angular` site

Comment: Could be, what can I do?

Comment: did you miss something in the inpect you've posted ? what you've posted as inspect-element does not have any open & close tags .

Comment: Just some background color data

Comment: in `angular` , instead of `value` the parameter `ng-model` is used . you can try to set that on this element which has `id="username"` .

Comment: @SowjanyaRBhat raises a good point. Even if you programmatically set the value in the DOM node, the change may not be reflected in the Angular model. If you're trying to automate something, it might be better to use Cypress or Selenium.

Comment: Ok I will try to find another way, thanks for the help